# Why does this simple java array program skip the first input?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

When I try to run this simple java program that asks how many words you would like the array to contain and asks you to enter a word at each index in the array, it skips the first input and prints "Enter a word ->" twice. For example, when I declare the length of my array as 4, it only asks me three times to enter a word.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ArrayPractice 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] words;
        int index;
        int numberOfWords;

        System.out.println("How many words in the array -> ");
        numberOfWords = input.nextInt();

        words = new String[numberOfWords];
        
        for (index = 0; index < words.length; index++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter a word -> ");
                words[index] = input.nextLine();
            }
        
        for (index = 0; index < words.length; index++)
            {
                System.out.println(words[index]);
            }
        
        input.close();
    }
}
```